# Rails 3.1 asset pipeline with suburis

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

I'm trying to convert a Rails 3.1 app to use the asset pipeline.  Currently using Rails 3.2.0.rc2. I'm setting `ENV['RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT']` to the suburi in application.rb. The helpers work fine, generating the correct path (including the suburi) to the file, however Rails routes aren't serving the files off of that path.

For instance, `<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'screen', :media => 'screen' %>` correctly generates the code `<link href="/my-suburi/assets/screen.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`, however Rails won't serve anything off of this address.

If I manually point my browser at `http://localhost:3000/my-suburi/assets/screen.css` I get a ActionController::RoutingError. However, if I point it at `http://localhost:3000/assets/screen.css` I get the file.  Everything else works fine with the sub-uris.

Anybody have any idea what I might be missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out myself.  In `application.rb`, I added...

```
config.assets.prefix = "/my-suburi"
```

and then restarted the server.  That changed the path in the header to be `"/my-suburi/screen.css"` (notice the lack of 'assets'), but I confirmed that it is correctly pulling from the /app/assets/stylesheets folder, now.