# what is the correct way to setup rails 3 + asset pipeline + suburi + apache/passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, asset-pipeline, assets

We are using Rails 3.2.17 with Apache/Passenger.

The biggest problem seems to be correctly resolving sub-uris. Advice varies with several different mechanisms to do suburi resolution.  However the information on how to properly configure a Rails app for suburis is scattered across many layers of the technology stack and it is difficult to find a constellation of settings that provides consistent behavior.

## configurations

- apache-passenger config (based on https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#_deploying_a_rack_based_ruby_application_including_rails_gt_3): 

  `RackBaseURI /suburi
  <Location /suburi>
  RackEnv production
  SetEnv RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT "/suburi"
  </Location>`
- `config.assets.prefix='/suburi'` - [Rails 3.1 asset pipeline with suburis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8828472/rails-3-1-asset-pipeline-with-suburis)
- `config.relative_url_root='/suburi'` or `ENV[RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT]='/suburi'` - http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#deploy-to-a-subdirectory-relative-url-root
- `Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:script_name] = '/suburi'` - https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/6933

And several others (from [How to deploy Rails 3.1 app in a subdirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7295744/how-to-deploy-rails-3-1-app-in-a-subdirectory))

- `map '/suburi'` in config.ru
- `scope '/suburi'` in routes.rb
- `RailsBaseUri` (not `RackBaseUri` as mentioned above -- is this simply old info, or still relevant for Rails 3.2.17/Passenger 3?

## contexts

I have tried each of these methods in three different contexts:

- Rails webrick: `rails s` @ http://example.com:3000/suburi/ (or http://example.com:3000/ *if* all the assets and urls still work!)
- Rails running under Apache/Passenger using `RackEnv development` @ http://example.com/suburi
- Rails running under Apache/Passenger using `RackEnv production` @ http://example.com/suburi

In every permutation I've tried, different things work and different things fail.

For example, in one permutation, assets are served from '/assets/...' while the rest of the app is served from '/suburi/...'  In others, '/suburi/assets' are served, except for font-url references from the sass files (generated by rails I might add).  Those references seem to still use '/assets/...' as if the variables setting suburi aren't used consistently between the erb helpers and the sass helpers.

Many, many times (too many to count actually) we get something working with webrick, only to have it fail in passenger deployment.  Or we get it working under Passenger in development to only have it fail in production.  There seem to be a lot of *magic* variables at different levels of this technology stack and very few comprehensive guides as to how to stitch everything together successfully.

## solutions?

I'm looking for a constellation of settings from the above references that provides consistent behavior under the three contexts I've provided.

The perfect solution would allow all three contexts to run exactly the same, with nothing broken (meaning assets work correctly, fonts work correctly, plugins from other gems and vendor assets work correctly, especially when cross-referencing files with standard Rails url helpers like font-url, etc.)

An adequate solution would enable the Passenger deployed apps to work equally well whether `development` or `production` (i.e. we would rather not get rudely surprised by gems and/or other js/css solutions we add in that seem to be working fine in development that don't work in production.

A minimal solution would enable all these pieces to work only in production.

It is also useful to know if the consensus is that the desired behavior cannot be achieved in Rails 3.  In that event we will likely back out from using the asset pipeline.